# powershell bash loops are randomly stuck waiting for keyboard input

Tags: bash, loops, powershell, input, wait

I have bash script I am running from powershell in windows that does a `for` loop.  Every once in a while, one of the loop iteration hangs until I hit enter on the keyboard.
This doesn't happen all the time, in fact, it happens pretty rarely, but it still does.

The interesting thing is that my loop innards is basically `time _command_` and so after I hit enter, it'll tell me how long the command took to run.  The command actually takes way less time to execute than the loop iteration takes - because it's waiting for keyboard input for some odd reason.

It's pretty annoying to leave a script running overnight and come back in the morning to see that it didn't get very far.

Does someone knows WHY this happens and WHAT to do to get around it?

Thanks,
jbu

Comment: I'm afraid we'll need more information.  Any one of the *commands* you run could potentially ask the user for input.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not an executable that nobody else has.  But it does not require user input.

Comment: And like I say, because _time_ marks the command as having finished earlier than when I push enter, it indicates that the command itself does not wait for input.

Comment: "Unfortunately it's not an executable that nobody else has." What the heck does that mean?

Comment: it means it's a program that the company wrote...so none of you guys would have it.

Comment: Unfortunately it **is** an executable that nobody else has.

Comment: show how your bash script looks like.

Answer (score 7):

I have encountered the same problem several times. Now I guess I have found the reason!

If you ever press the mouse within the powershell, it might get stuck and need user to press "enter" to continue. So the get-around-way is to make sure that you didn't accidentally press your mouse within the shell window while you are already running some program...

Comment: This also happens with console applications. Basically the window is waiting for a selection to be made, so it just waits.

Comment: I find this is exactly my case! 100% reproducible!! Solved the issue that I have been wondering for years!! Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks but it's quite painful if you often need to copy-paste from the terminal (since it disable the possibility, and you have to re-enable it each time).

Answer (score 2):

Goto the powershell properties and unselect `'Quick Edit'/'Insert'` check boxes. If these are selected, the console pauses output and resumes only when an Enter key is pressed ( You can identify this by monitoring the console title bar- it will switch from `"Administrator:Windows PowerShell"` to `"Select Administrator:Windows Powershell"`

Comment: how do you access Powershell Properties in Win10?

Answer (score 0):

Until you post the script, there's little we can do to help.

However, in general, one of your commands probably returns a null once in a while as input to stdin of another command which, upon seeing null looks to the terminal as stdin. Or something along those lines.